# Itunes 12.2 format playlist as songs not working

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, mac

I am aware that there is supposed to be a little dropdown in the upper, right-hand corner of Itunes that allows one to change the format of a playlist. However, my Itunes looks like this:

[image]

How do I get my formatting dropdown back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With iTunes 12, playlists can be displayed as a Playlist (your current setting and it seems to be the default), or as Songs, Albums, Artists, Composers or Genres. Change the setting from the menu bar at `View->View As`, or use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to open `Show View Options`.

There is no dropdown for the how playlists are viewed.